# How do I make changes to mouse pointer appearance, using Unity Tweak Tool, to stay in place when restarting the computer from shutdown?

Tags: pointers

After selecting Red glass in large size for pointer appearance using Unity Tweak Tool in Ubuntu 16.04.1 64bit on System 76 Kudu laptop, the arrow initially appears correctly. However, so far I have found it reverts to a small Red glass arrow in the following situations:

1. When I shutdown the computer (it took a long time to do this after this change) and then restarted.
2. When I was almost through with increasing the font sizes by one point in all the fields for Fonts i.e. it seemed to hold initially but then reverted. I have since returned all font changes back to default, but would like to be able to make changes there if necessary.

I am attempting to set up the laptop to suit my *particular sight and other physical impairments*, being familiar with doing this on a *Windows 7 32 bit Dell Vostro laptop*.

Comment: Please do this `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade` lets make sure everything is up to date.

Comment: Thank you George. I had already done this following advice from System76. They also advised on adding a command to Startup Applications which I did. I now find that on startup, the redglass pointer is sometimes large and sometimes the default small size. I have not yet spotted a consistent pattern that leads to this difference after several tests.